# terminal command is running inside docker container but the same command is not running from local machine

Tags: c++, linux, docker, terminal

## Running docker container in iterative mode

- Files present inside the cpp_test directory in docker container:

  root@ad2d85985536:/usr/src/cpp_test# ls

  core    input    input.txt    main    test.cpp
- Running execution command (c++ file) inside the docker container through iterative CLI:

  root@ad2d85985536:/usr/src/cpp_test# ./main <input.txt>output1.txt

  root@ad2d85985536:/usr/src/cpp_test# ls

  core  input  input.txt  main  output1.txt  test.cpp

As you can see the output1.txt file is created.

- But if I run the same command from my local machine terminal using the docker exec command my execution doesn't work. As shown below:

  ┌──(legion㉿kali)-[~/dev/OJ/docker]
  └─$ docker exec --workdir /usr/src/cpp_test checker  ./main.exe  < input.txt > output1.txt

  zsh: no such file or directory: input.txt

I get the error as no such file is present. But when I try to access the input.txt file using the same docker exec command I can access it without any problem.

Please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Is that all one command line? You're redirecting input to the docker command from input.txt? That's probably not what you want, as input.txt is inside the container. Did you include quotes so the input and output redirection becomes part of the command?

As written, that command is akin to:

```
docker < input.txt ... a bunch of options ...
```

Comment: No they were in 2 separate command lines.  Please can you tell the command which includes quotes.

Comment: @PranjalBhatt Perhaps edit your question so it's absolutely clear what command you're running.